# Can this modified BLEU score problem be solved greedily?

Tags: algorithm, greedy, bleu

```
Given:
1. A list of strings
2. A reference string
3. x where x is an int

Pick out x strings from 1 to get the candidate string such that the BLEU score with the reference string is as high as possible.
```

I know the naive solution will be to get all possible x length strings and then calculate [the BLEU score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLEU) for all of them and choose the best one.

I wonder if I can do this greedily?

For a [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm), we need to prove two properties: 1) Greedy Choice property and 2) Optimal Substructure. I however, have not been able to prove or disprove it so far.